# How to use css selector to test an hybrid mobile application with Appium?

Tags: css-selectors, mocha.js, appium, hybrid-mobile-app, webdriver-io

I'm a recent web development student, and I'm doing my internship in an association. I'm working on their application. It's an application that allows you to view content, to learn lessons (memos for manual jobs). 
**Context :**
It is a hybrid application coded in html, js, css, which was built with Cordova. The goal for them was to go for the simplest, without having to learn other languages to develop the application, so the choice was made on Cordova.
Now, the goal is to deploy a test environment (doing javascript coded tests on features), for android and windows.
To do these tests, I have to use selectors to select my elements (select an input for example: the login field for example) in order to create an interaction (pass a value in this input for example, and click on the login button for example), and thus simulate the behaviour of a user who would use the application.
To do these tests I use appium.
**What I would like to do :**
I'm just looking for a selector that can be recognized whatever the android version (marshmallow, nougat, Q, R etc) and whatever the device model.
In order to simplify the writing and the implementation of these tests, I used the Mocha framework.
**What I have already tried**
I started by using the xpath selector, but it's not recommended, and depending on the android versions and smartphone models, I realized that this selector is not recognized, and therefore unusable.
You can also use different selectors, among which the id, the name, but each time I am confronted with the same error message that makes their use impossible.
Here is for the windows and android platforms, the error message I get when I try to use a CSS selector (id and byName, and text) :

ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to Error: Locator Strategy 'css selector' is not supported for this session.

I tried several solutions, in vain, so I can't make any progress, and this is a course that I do almost completely independently, as volunteers are almost never available.

Comment: You have to switch to webview first.

Comment: @MikeG. We've already tried to switch to webview.
The enableRemoteDebugging is set as "true", we tried it with the following desired capability:
then, with that:
 "autoWebview": "true"
chromedriverChromeMappingFile:{
    "2.34": "61.0.3163"
  }
 and we always get the same error message "encountered internal error running command: Error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '61.0.3163'".
[image du probleme][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LwgA.png

Comment: Not sure about auto webview flag. Try without it first, do everything manually. I don't know why you need mapping file, chromedriver 2.34 is outdated and won't ever work, let appium download the proper version of chromedriver instead. There is chromedriver autodownload appium capability

Comment: @MikeG.thank you for your answer; unfortunately the problem is not solved. In the Appium log we can see a problem with Chromedriver ( v. 2.20.353145 does not fully support W3C protocol. Defaulting to MJSONWP" )...

Comment: As I mentioned above don't use outdated chromedriver versions, they can't work. Share your capabilities, please. Also, do you use selenium grid or working with appium directly? What is your android and appium versions? You are missing basically all the information in the question

Comment: @MikeG.I installed the latest version of chromedriver (npm install chromedriver) which is supposed to install the most up to date version.
For the desired capabilities:
  capabilities:[{
        "platformName": "android",
        "automationName": "UiAutomator2",
        "udid": "emulator-5554",
       "appPackage": "com.downloader.tvetacademy",
        "appActivity": ".MainActivity",
        "selfGrantingPermissions": "true",
        "noReset": "true",
        "autoWebview": "true",
    }]
We use webdriverio. appium version v1.18.3, android API 27

Comment: Have you read my previous comments? Remove autoWebview, you don't need chromedriver in dependencies, appium downloads it for you when needed with chromedriver_autodownload capability set to true

Comment: Have you read my previous comments? Remove autoWebview, you don't need chromedriver in dependencies, appium downloads it for you when needed with chromedriver_autodownload capability set to true

Comment: @MikeG. The problem is solved, thank you very much Mike!

Comment: Wow, amazing, can you please post the proper answer?

Comment: @MikeG.I spoke too fast! Actually it only worked for android and not for windows! 
I get this error: WARN webdriver: Request failed with status 
500 due to Locator Strategy 'css selector' is not supported for this session
0-0] Error in "Connection test should warn for incorrect entries".
Locator Strategy 'css selector' is not supported for this session